# a,b,c are different from 0, find every divisors of c that are between a and b, a and b can be included. But you cannot use loop

Tags: python

```
a,b,c=5,25,10
def divisors(a,b,c):
    def divs(a, b, c, l=[], d=1):
        if (c % d == 0) & (min(a, b) <= d <= max(a, b)):
            l.append(d)
        if d == c:
            return None
        divs(a, b, c, l, d + 1)
        return l
    if a!=0 and b!=0 and c!=0:
        return len(divs(a,b,c))
    else:
        print("A,B,C Ar unda iyos 0")
        return False

print(divisors(a,b,c))
```

#Here i used Recursion but i was told that i cannot use recursion because it is similar to loop. is there any possible way to do that without loop or recursion.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. What is the expected output with that input `5, 25, 10`? Is it `5` and `10` as they are both factors of `10`?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I think it's the number of divisors, which is `2`.

Comment: a,b,c can be random numbers legit. it just requires this numbers to be different from 0 and c divisors must be in range of a-b or b-a. the main question is there anyway to find divisors of c without loops and recursion built-in functions cannot even be touched

Comment: What a bizarre question!  You're sure there's an actual answer?  Without recursion or a loop, it seems that there is a fixed upper bound on how long your program can run. But the actual running time of the program depends on the size of the input.

Comment: is this our test? or you are looking for solution to achieve your desired result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.